# Create unique integers

Tags: python

Please help, I am trying to create unique numbers in python. I want to use this method which to me at least makes good sense. Thanks in advance and I have tried my best for 4 hours of painful screen staring before posting this :-)

```
def createOrderNum():
    orderNum = random.randint(48,56)
    filesize = os.path.getsize("customers.txt")
    if filesize == 0:
        print("The file is empty: " + str(filesize))
        return(orderNum)
    else:
        print("The file is not empty: " + str(filesize))
    exists = False
    while exists == False:
        with open('customers.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                
                if str(orderNum) == line.split(',')[1]:
                    print('number exists')
                    createOrderNum()
                else:
                    print('not exists')
        if exists == False:
            return orderNum
```

Comment: You want to create unique integers and then append them to a file. Is it the output you want

Comment: `return createOrderNum()`? ... what exactly is the problem?

Comment: why do you want to create unique numbers?why not a uuid by hash code

Comment: Please edit the question so it's clear what's being asked. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta) link might help.

Comment: Yes, I want to create them and append them to a file but ..... they repeat. I realise that there are better ways but I just want to do it this way since I am learning python and in my head the principle of this 'should' work :-) Thanks for the replies guys :-)

Comment: Currently this function allows repeated numbers to be appended

Comment: I think your problem is that `line.split(',')[1]` will give things line "55\n" if it's the last position or possibly "55 " (with a space). Then you wouldn't match with the generated number. Add a print statement that shows what you are comparing. Or even better, use a debugger :)

Comment: Thanks, ill try that. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `uuid` to generate unique identifier?

```
>>> import uuid
>>> uuid.uuid4()
UUID('bd65600d-8669-4903-8a14-af88203add38')
>>> str(uuid.uuid4())
'f50ec0b7-f960-400d-91f0-c42a6d44e3d0'
>>> uuid.uuid4().hex
'9fe2c4e93f654fdbb24c02b15259716c'
```

Answer (score 0):

First the whole working code:

```
import os
import random


def createOrderNum(old_numbers=None):
    orderNum = random.randint(48, 56)
    if old_numbers is None:
        old_numbers= get_old_numbers()

    if orderNum in old_numbers:
        print('number exists')
        orderNum=createOrderNum(old_numbers)
    else:
        print('not exists')
    return orderNum


def get_old_numbers():
    my_numbers = []
    filesize = os.path.getsize("customers.txt")
    if filesize == 0:
        print("The file is empty: " + str(filesize))
        return my_numbers  # lets just return an empty list if it is empty
    else:
        print("The file is not empty: " + str(filesize))
    with open('customers.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            my_numbers.append(int(line.split(',')[1].strip()))
    return my_numbers

def add_number(x:int):
    with open('customers.txt', 'a+') as f:
        f.write(f"asdf,{x}\n")

add_number(createOrderNum())
```

Ok i think i kinda get what you wan to do.
Your algortihm should work like:

1. Create random number
2. if number is in file go back to 1
3. append number to file

I think that makes sense and is reasonable.
You can do that two ways. In a loop or recursive. You tried it recursive so lets do it hthat way.
From your code its not clear how the content of the file looks like and how you add the new number to the file. That makes it a bit tricky but i will guess and i think it will help you.
I will change some of the code to make it easier to work with.
First thing you can  remove the `exists` variable. It does nothing.

```
def createOrderNum():
    orderNum = random.randint(48, 56)
    filesize = os.path.getsize("customers.txt")
    if filesize == 0:
       print("The file is empty: " + str(filesize))
        return (orderNum)
    else:
        print("The file is not empty: " + str(filesize))

    with open('customers.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if str(orderNum) == line.split(',')[1]:
                print('number exists')
                createOrderNum()
            else:
                print('not exists')
        return orderNum
```

Next lets move the file reading and extracting the numbers to a new function so its easier to test and think about.

```
def get_old_numbers():
    my_numbers = []
    filesize = os.path.getsize("customers.txt")
    if filesize == 0:
        print("The file is empty: " + str(filesize))
        return my_numbers  # lets just return an empoty list if it is empty
    else:
        print("The file is not empty: " + str(filesize))

    with open('customers.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            my_numbers.append(int(line.split(',')[1].strip())) #lets remove whitepsace with strip and cast the strings to integers to make comparing later easier
    return my_numbers
```

And now we use that in createOrderNum:

```
def createOrderNum():
    orderNum = random.randint(48, 56)
    old_numbers= get_old_numbers()

    
    for number in old_numbers:
        if str(orderNum) == number:
            print('number exists')
            createOrderNum() # the return is not used. Why not?
        else:
            print('not exists')
    return orderNum
```

Here we can see that you dont use the return of createOrderNum. Lets change that too.

```
def createOrderNum():
    orderNum = random.randint(48, 56)
    old_numbers= get_old_numbers()
    for number in old_numbers:
        if orderNum == number:
            print('number exists')
            orderNum = createOrderNum() #we have to acutaly 
        else:
            print('not exists')
    return orderNum
```

Now we have the problem that createOrderNum is called multiple times in the loop everytime the numbers are the same. so lets change it a bit.

```
def createOrderNum():
    orderNum = random.randint(48, 56)
    old_numbers= get_old_numbers()

    if orderNum in old_numbers:
        print('number exists')
        orderNum=createOrderNum()
    else:
        print('not exists')
    return orderNum
```

We need one more function to add our results to the file:

```
def add_number(x:int):
with open('customers.txt', 'a+') as f:
    f.write(f"other data you have,{x}\n")
#try it
add_number(createOrderNum())
```

One more optimization so we dont have to open the file multiple times for one functioncall:

```
def createOrderNum(old_numbers=None):
    orderNum = random.randint(48, 56)
    if old_numbers is None: 
        old_numbers= get_old_numbers()

    if orderNum in old_numbers:
        print('number exists')
        orderNum=createOrderNum(old_numbers)
    else:
        print('not exists')
    return orderNum
```